# Continuity of a definite integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an absolutely integrable function, and let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the definite integral $$F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$ I need to show that $F$ is continuous, i.e., that for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|F(x)-F(x_0)|=|\int_{[x,x_0]} f(t) dt|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-x_o|< \delta$. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that it is sequentially continous. Consider a sequence $(x_n)$ convergning to $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and  the associed sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \chi_{[-\infty,x_n]}f(t)$. We have $|f_n|(t) \leq |f|(t)$ which is integrable. By the Lebesgue's dominated convegrence theorem, we get $$\lim_{n\to \infty}F(x_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(t) \mathrm{d}t =  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[-\infty,x]}f(t)\mathrm{d}t = F(x).$$

A function is sequentially continous iff it is continous in «$\epsilon-\delta$»